# How to assertRaises a specific exception

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have following code:

```
def foo(input):
    if not input.startswith("prefix"):
        raise Exception("input should start with prefix!")
    process(input)
```

Now I want to unit test this function; when `input` is not starting with `"prefix"` it can actually throw an exception. Here's my `unittest` code:

```
def test_foo_invalud_type(self):
    self.assertRaises(Exception, foo, 999)
```

The problem with this test code is: it catches the exception, but the exception is `'int' object has no attribute 'startswith'`, instead of `input should start with prefix!`. The test will pass, but it's not a good test. How can I identify the two exceptions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`raise Exception` is very bad form - try to be more specific when raising exceptions. Using such a general exception makes it really difficult to distinguish between the two different cases you're trying to test for.

In this case, for example, I think `ValueError` would be most appropriate within `foo`, as it's the right type of thing (a string) but doesn't have the right value (no `'prefix'` at the start).

```
def foo(input):
    if not input.startswith("prefix"):
        raise ValueError("input should start with prefix!")
    process(input)
```

This lets you distinguish between the *type* of the input being wrong (which raises an `AttributeError` due to the absence of `.startswith`*):

```
def test_foo_invalid_type(self):  # note fixed typo in 'invalud'
    self.assertRaises(AttributeError, foo, 999)  # and more specific error
```

and the *value* of the input being wrong (the `ValueError` explicitly raised for a missing `'prefix'` prefix):

```
def test_foo_invalid_value(self):
    with self.assertRaises(ValueError) as cm:
       foo('no prefix')
       self.assertEqual(
           cm.exception.args, 
           ('input should start with prefix!',),
       )
```

Note how you can use the `with` context manager form of [`assertRaises`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) to get access to the error itself. This allows you to also check that the correct message is being provided for the error.

---

* You could even consider handling the `AttributeError` *within* `foo`, and raising a `TypeError` instead. That seems like a more natural fit for *"that parameter was the wrong type"*.

Comment: I think I misinterpreted the question at least twice, but I'm happy with that now...

Comment: Thank you. I have to admit that my question was a bad description.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an int to your function `foo` but it looks like you wanted a str (as you're using `startswith` on the `input` parameter). Your unit test should be:

```
def test_foo_invalud_type(self):
    self.assertRaises(Exception, foo, '999')
```

Answer (score 0):

The line that is raising the error is:

```
if not input.startswith("prefix"):
```

And not:

```
    raise Exception("input should start with prefix!")
```

Because you are passing an int instead a string: 999 instead '999'

Remember that int, have not an attribute startswith.

Answer (score 0):

Simply implement and raise your own exception.

```
class BadStartException(Exception):
    pass

def foo(input):
    if not input.startswith("prefix"):
        raise BadStartException("input should start with prefix!")
    process(input)

def test_foo_invalud_type(self):
    self.assertRaises(BadStartException, foo, 999)
```

Note that your test would fail now. I'm not sure if that's what you wanted to test.

Comment: But the problem is that `foo(999)` doesn't `raise BadStartException`, it's an `AttributeError`!

Comment: @jonrsharpe that is a problem with `foo`, not a problem with this answer. Don't raise `Exception`!